# The distance $\epsilon$ between two image points in a iterated linear map

Tags: discrete-mathematics, chaos-theory, complex-dynamics

Consider

$$x_{n+1}
=f \left( x_{n} \right)
= \begin{cases}
x_{n} & 0\leq x_{n}< 0.5 \\
x_{n}-1 & 0.5\leq x_{n}\leq 1
\end{cases}.$$

Restricting our case to the interval $0\leq x_{n}\leq 0.5$:

For any ‘small’ $\epsilon$ infinitesimally close to $x$:

$$\left \| x-\left ( x+\epsilon  \right ) \right \|=\left | \epsilon  \right |$$

But why does

$$\left | f\left ( x \right )-f\left ( x+\epsilon  \right ) \right |=\left | 2\epsilon  \right |?$$

Comment: Is there a typo in the definition of $f$? Maybe you meant $1-x_n$ for the second case... Otherwise $f(f(3/4))$ is undefined.

Comment: I wouldn't know. It came from my lecture notes.

Comment: I think that there is a typo in the definition of $f$. The current one cannot be iterated...

Comment: Thanks. It's worthwhile for me to bring this up to my prof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That factor $2$ is wrong.

For $x < 0.5$ and $x+ε<0.5$, we have:

$$  \left| f(x) - f(x+ε) \right|
  = \left | x- (x+ε) \right |
  = \left | ε \right |$$

More generally, for sufficiently small $ε$, you have:

$$ \frac{f(x+ε)-f(x)}{ε} = f'(x),$$

which you only need to rearrange to find $\left| f(x) - f(x+ε) \right|.$